# Insert Polars column with a dict to PostgreSQL with JSONB format

Tags: postgresql, dataframe, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, python-polars

I'm trying to insert a Polars column containing dict in PostgreSQL by using the polar built-in [write_database](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_database.html). During the insertion I would like that column formatted as JSONB in PostgreSQL to be more practical using SQL in the future. But after multiple failed attempt I'm still struggling to find the solution.

```
df.with_columns(
      pl.col("struct_containing_multiple_info")
      .apply(lambda x: x["dict_formatted_column"])
      .alias("dict_formatted_column")
)

return df.write_database(
      table_name=schema + "." + table_name,
      connection=postgres_resource.url,
      engine="sqlalchemy",
      if_exists="replace",
)
```

- By using `json.dumps(x["dict_formatted_column"])` I'm loosing the json format, which is inserting as a text
- By using [register_adapter on psycopg2](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation) i'm getting the error: `TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable`
- By using adbc as the engine i'm getting the error : `adbc_driver_manager.NotSupportedError: NOT_IMPLEMENTED: [libpq] Field #9 ('dict_formatted_column') has unsupported type for ingestion struct`
- By using nothing i'm getting the error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'dict'`

If any of you has a clue to fix that issue I would gladly appreciate it :D

Comment: 1) `polars.write_database()` is a work in progress. I have filed a couple of issues. To the projects credit they have fixed them very quickly. 2) `psycopg2` can adapt JSON but you need to follow the directions here [JSON](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) e.g. use `JSON({'key': 'value'})`. 3) I'm guessing the `polars` use of SQLAlchemy may not do 2). I would search for existing issue here [Polars Issues](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues) and in absence of one file an issue.

Comment: I should have added that in the `polars` SQLAlchemy case the `polars.df` gets converted to a `pandas.df` before it is passed to SQLAlchemy. Also the `SQLAlchemy` engine uses INSERTs to load the table versus COPY as used by the `adbc` engine. For a data set of any size this really slows things down.

Comment: Add dummy sample data.

Comment: You might also take a look at [json_encode](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.struct.json_encode.html#polars.Expr.struct.json_encode).

Comment: Unless you're using the adbc engine, the meat and potatoes of the method is `.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array=True).to_sql(...)` It might be that converting a struct column with `use_pyarrow_extension_array=True` is broken or it might be that pandas can't do it either. Incidentally, you should upgrade your [polars version](https://pola.rs/posts/polars-0-19-upgrade-guide/) you're quite behind.